# Validation not working properly for ValidationMessageFor method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am having problem with mvc's `ValidationMessageFor()` function extension.

The problem is its showing error message on get request means that the message appears before post.

Here is my http get action

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Post()
{
    foreach (ModelState modelState in ViewData.ModelState.Values)
    {
        foreach (ModelError error in modelState.Errors)
        {
           // DoSomethingWith(error);
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

and

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.title, "Title*", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

my model class field `title` is marked with required attribute

I have added validation js files of query.
Also have looked the Qs on SO but the solution there is of no use
i.e. I have added this to view

```
@{ Html.EnableClientValidation(); }
```

But no good outcome.

Is it a bug? How to resolve this? All web searches and SO questions are proven useless.

Comment: The only way that you can get a `ModelStateError` in a GET method is if contains parameters for your model or your adding them in your code. But because its named `title`, you may have a conflict with the `ViewBag.Title = ...` code that is in the standard MVC view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke as you can see I am not using Viewbag.title in my action nether in my view. and I am not having any parameter in my get method. What else do you mean?

Comment: @StephenMuecke In ModelStateError there are no errors

Comment: No I said the  `ViewBag.Title` code that is in the **view** (at the top of the `.cshtml` file)

Comment: @StephenMuecke nope I removed but no effect still showing error on get

Comment: Just go into the layout file used by that view and temporarily comment of the `title>@ViewBag.Title</title>` and see if the validation message is still being displayed (and I'm assuming its _The field title is required_?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have already. and added another field to check showing error on that too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137265/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-alex).

Comment: @StephenMuecke you need to look at `Post` action in LHCONTROLLER. sorry for late reply